# Action bar doesn't show items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-styles

I am developing an android app supporting API-9, the action bar with the name of the app appear but the problem is that items doesn't appear
this is the menu file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.fakher.actualitefoot -->
    <!-- Settings -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never|withText" />

    <!-- Check updates -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_check_updates"
        app:showAsAction="never|withText" />

</menu>
```

the main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private PagerAdapter adapter;
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ....
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private Drawable.Callback drawableCallback = new Drawable.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(who);
        }

        @Override
        public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
            handler.postAtTime(what, when);
        }

        @Override
        public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(what);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        adView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        adView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

stykes.xml :

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_window</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <!--<item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>-->
        <item name="android:background">#ff127d08</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

i want that the action bar show the menu containing items declared in the menu file
Thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to use the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport. If that is the case, you have to inherit from `AppCompatActivity` (or its predecessor, `ActionBarActivity`), not `FragmentActivity`. Since `AppCompatActivity` and `ActionBarActivity` themselves extend `FragmentActivity`, you will not lose any fragment-related functionality.

Also:

- Change all `getActionBar()` calls to `getSupportActionBar()`
- Ensure that your theme is inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat` (or from something else that inherits from `Theme.AppCompat`

Comment: how can i change themes to make it inherite from Theme.AppCompat ?

this is the <style> of my application :
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>

Comment: @SaHa: Change `parent="android:Theme.Light"` to `parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light"`

Comment: it generated this error : Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: i put the whole file in question. i can add styles/11 and styles/14 if you want, Thanks :)

Comment: @SaHa: Whoops, sorry, my mistake. That should be `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"`, without the `android:` part.

Comment: error is chaned now : "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
" please take a look at the whole styles.xml file in my question

Comment: @SaHa: Everywhere in your `styles.xml` that you are referring to something other than `AppCompat` (e.g., `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse`), you either need to remove it or replace it with something that is `AppCompat`-based.

Comment: this become another issue, i asked another question, this is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457212/action-bar-doesnt-accept-personal-styles
thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

What stands out to me is that you have- `app:showAsAction="never|withText"`,
the "never" parameter will prevent the item from appearing. I think it should be changed to:

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

or:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

the "withText" may also mess it up. I'm new to android programming, so I may be wrong. but check that and let me know if it worked. And also, I can't see all of the code, But did you import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar (since the app is for API 9)? it won't function without that as well.